# How to filter the strings without using regex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm filtering the array of strings with a matching character. The task is to get the strings with the character "o" from first part of the word.

```js
const fruits =["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"]

const character = "o"

const filterdFruits = fruits.filter((item) => item.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === character.toLowerCase())

console.log(filterdFruits)
```

The above logic will return the character matching with first letter of the string, which is Orange. But what I'm expecting here is to include Orange, apple orange as part my answer. There is  reason why I want Orange to be in first place as it is an exact match and, while, apple orange is also a match but not an exact match. I'm reluctant to use regex here as I have the tendency to go wrong. Happy to get some directions :)

Comment: split by space and do the same in a loop

Comment: `fruits.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(character)).sort((a,b) => a.toLowerCase().indexOf(character) - b.toLowerCase().indexOf(character))
` ?

Comment: @cmgchess "appric**o**t" does not start with "o". Neither does "carr**o**t". And many others.

Comment: @VLAZ now only i understood the question

Comment: @ cmgchess I attempted this way before, but order will go wrong if I have 
const fruits =["apple orange", "The Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"]. In this case, I'd expect ["apple orange", "The Orange"] as the order because they fall in same position.

Comment: @user2824374 I added an answer, did you get a chance to look into that ? Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Comment: @Rohit - It works for a single character, but not for more than 1. For instance character="or" is returning null array. I somehow managed to get this issue resolved using RegEx, but I couldn't get this done without using RegEx.

Comment: @user2824374 As we are doing comparision by using `charAt(0)` that's the reason it was not working for more than 1 character. I updated my answer. Now it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal - Thanks man. Substring helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your strings in your array, using a regular expression (I know you said you were reluctant to use them as you feel you may go wrong, but I thought I'd show some examples) may be enough. Here we match on a word boundary `\b`, followed by an `o`:

```js
const fruits =["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"]
const filterdFruits = fruits.filter(item => /\bo/i.test(item))
console.log(filterdFruits)
```

The word boundary is zero-length, and [matches the following](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

The first and last options allow us to match both `"Orange"` and `"apple orange"`. Note that the word boundary matches between non-word characters, so `apple $orange` would also be a valid match. We can change the regex a little to fix this case, where we only match words that start with `o` (`^o`) or (`|`) have an `o` following a whitespace character `\so` that is not preceded by (`(?<!)`) the beginning of the string `^`:

```js
const fruits =["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"]
const filterdFruits = fruits.filter(item => /^o|(?<!^)\so/i.test(item))
console.log(filterdFruits)
```

In both expressions above, the `/i` means do a case-insensitive match. To make the above expressions dynamic so that they use the `character`, with can use the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp), eg:

```js
const fruits = ["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"];
const character = "o";
const filterdFruits = fruits.filter(item => new RegExp(String.raw`\b${character}`, 'i').test(item))
console.log(filterdFruits)
```

If `character` is user-supplied, you need to start worrying about [escaping your `character` string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) so that regex can't be inserted as a value. There aren't any native ways to escape a string so that it can be used in a regular expression, so at that point, you might consider using a different approach such as [Terry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72814579/5648954)

Comment: Thanks Nick. I like this approach

`fruits.filter(item => new RegExp(String.raw`\b${character}`, 'i').test(item)).sort((a,b) => a.toLowerCase().indexOf(character) - b.toLowerCase().indexOf(character))`

Answer (score 1):

A small change to split each input on space(s) and to check each resulting word for a first letter of 'o' should work:

```js
const fruits = ["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", 'plum kiwi Orange']

const character = "o"

const filterdFruits = fruits.filter((item) => { 
    return item.split(/\s+/).some(word => { 
        return word.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === character.toLowerCase()
    })
});

console.log(filterdFruits)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regexp `/\b[o]/gi` to identify words starting with `o`

**Important:** this will match `" Orange"`

```js
const fruits =["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"]
const filterdFruits = fruits.filter((item) => /\b[o]/i.test(item))

console.log(filterdFruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple approach by just using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const fruits =["apple orange", "Orange", "banana", "banana", "apple"];

const character = "or";

const filterdFruits = fruits.filter((item) => {
  const subStrLength = character.length;
  return item.split(' ').some(el => el.substring(0, subStrLength).toLowerCase() === character.toLowerCase())
});

console.log(filterdFruits);
```